# How can i convert string to date for alarm notification in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My Question is, I have a string something like that 07:25AM Now my question is how can i make this string to date for location notification for an alarm app.

So far i have done like this:

```
   NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
   NSDate * timeNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"07:25 AM"];
```

But it's showing this time: `1999-12-31 18:25:00 +0000` and i want something like this `todays date 7:25:00`

I am little bit new at date conversion so if someone help me then it will helpful for me.

Regards

Emon

Comment: Cheatsheet http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use `NSDateComponents`. It's a bit verbose, but it would look a little like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";

NSDate *timestamp = [formatter dateFromString:@"07:25 AM"];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *timestampComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:timestamp];
NSDateComponents *currentTimeComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate new]];
currentTimeComponents.hour = timestampComponents.hour;
currentTimeComponents.minute = timestampComponents.minute;

NSDate *result = [calendar dateFromComponents:currentTimeComponents];
```

Comment: If that did the trick for you, please mark my post as the answer ;)